# htaccess special characters issue : and _ and -

Tags: php, regex

i made a rewrite rule for my script but i have a little problem i want to add ( :,-,_ ) into the rule but i always get error

i use this code

> RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z]{1,200})$ go.php?s=$1 [L]

that code allowing to use a-z and A-Z and i want to add those symbols to the rule

the symbols are :

> : , - , _

to that code.

please help me to correct that code and i will be happy for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you tried?  The rule below adds the three characters (`:`, `_`, `-`) to your pattern:

`RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z:_-]{1,200})$ go.php?s=$1 [L]`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to update your regex a little bit for it.
Updated regex would be: `^([0-9a-zA-Z:_-]{1,200})$`